# how to parse a row only if one of its fields is bold? Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

so I have this code that collects all product info I need:

```
  # get main page
  page = agent.get "http://www.site.com.mx/tienda/index.php"

  search_form = page.forms.first

  search_result = agent.submit search_form

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(search_result.body)

  rows = doc.css("table.articulos tr")

        i = 0
        details = rows.collect do |row|
          detail = {}
          [
            [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
            [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
            [:qty, 'td[5]/text()'],
            [:qty2, 'td[5]/p/b/text()'],
            [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
          ].collect do |name, xpath|
            detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
          end
          i = i + 1
          detail
        end
```

I need to collect SKU as in my code (in a variable) if qty2 exists only.

Comment: How are you retrieving your rows?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to parse html. Have you looked at nokogiri?

Comment: Um, he's using Nokogiri, see question title, tags, and at_xpath() method.

Comment: Yes, I am using Nokogiri and this is a RUBY file.

Comment: It looks like you're using Mechanize to access the site. If so, Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally so you can ask it for a Nokogiri document, rather than parsing the body or simply tell it to `search`. See the "scraping data" section at the bottom of the [Getting Started With Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html) page.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I read some documentation on Mechanize site and Nokogiri, it says you can use a mechanize page as a nokogiri object. Now if I do use search this will get me the searched field and parse it, I need another field in same row, will this work?

Comment: Your HTML is malformed: You have `</a><a...>` outside the `td` blocks. Nokogiri will parse it, however it will rewrite the DOM to be correct. That can change the accessors needed because the correct markup may not match what your sample shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your row selection logic to get only the rows you want. **Update**: This will get the rows that **do** have the bold in the quantity cell:

```
rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]')
```

**Update 2**

Here's an example showing that this works.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<__html__
<html>
<table class="articulos">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>sku1</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2-1</td>
  <td>2-2</td>
  <td>sku2</td>
  <td>2-4</td>
  <td><p><b>2-5</b></p></td>
  <td>2-6</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
__html__

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]').each do |row|
  puts row.at_xpath('td[3]/text()')
end
```

Output:

```
sku2
```

Comment: rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[not(td[5])]')
will not interfere with bold if it is in same selection logic?

Comment: No interference because the selector is specifically looking for a p with a b inside, which must exist before it matches and gets excluded.

Comment: yes but I need the bold , and if I use not(td[5]) , bold is in same path as in td[5]  I just did this and it doesnt collect any data. because it is saying just to collect if td[5] is not present :S.. any idea ?

Comment: I guess it would be something like, if xpath td[5]/p/b/text() is present, collect xpath td[3]/text() ?? any idea how to set this up?

Comment: @ingalcala, I have updated my answer. I removed the not() and now it gives you the rows *with* bold, instead of non-bold.

Comment: I get a : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) , I think it is because other rows do exist but they dont have that condition. so I need to define the object?

Comment: @ingalcala, the presence of non-matching rows would not affect it. It is more likely the XPath doesn't match your XML. Can you provide a sample XML fragment (e.g. a complete table element)?

Comment: @Mark Thomas, I updated some info. I forgot to say I am using Mechanize. idk if that matters at all. 

xpath for bold is /x:html/x:body/x:a/x:center/x:table[2]/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:center[3]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[3]/x:td[5]/x:p/x:b

xpath for non bold is /x:html/x:body/x:a/x:center/x:table[2]/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:center[3]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[6]/x:td[5]

Comment: @ingalcala, my latest update shows how it's done in a complete example. You can adjust to your particular XPath needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right:

```
rows.collect{...}.reject{|detail| detail[:qty2].empty?}
```

or

```
rows.inject([]){ |details, row| ... ; detail[:qty2].empty? ? details : details.push(detail) }
```

Comment: I am sorry if I sound a bit dumb asking this. But do I add my code in your dots? or how is this going to work? thanks.

Comment: please help me understand sintax of both my code and your recomendation