# How do I integrate these two conditions block codes to mine in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

How do I integrate these two conditions if my code scrapes without them? My code is working already, but it scrapes all rows (non-bold and bold values) and doesn't scrape the title attribute string.

---

**Condition 1:  [parses a table row only if one of its fields is bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433808/how-to-parse-a-row-only-if-one-of-its-fields-is-bold-nokogiri-and-ruby):**

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]').each do |row|
puts row.at_xpath('td[3]/text()')
end
```

---

**Condition2: [gets only the number off the title attribute string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449208/how-to-parse-only-part-of-a-string-value-from-an-element-using-nokogiri-ruby-me) :**

```
doc     = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
numbers = doc.xpath('//p[@title]').collect { |p| p[:title].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
```

---

**My code:**

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(search_result.body)
rows = doc.css("table.articulos tr")
i = 0
details = rows.each do |row|
  detail = {}  
  [
    [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
    [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
    [:qty, 'td[5]/text()'],
    [:qty2, 'td[5]/p/b/text()'],
    [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end
  i = i + 1
  detail
end
```

**A second attempt:**

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(search_result.body)
  rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]')
  i = 0
  details = rows.each do |row|
    detail = {}  
    [
      [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
      [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
      [:stock, "td[5]/p[@title]"],
      [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
    ].each do |name, xpath|
        detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip

      end
    i = i + 1
    if detail[:sku] != ""
          price = detail[:price].split

          if price[1] == "D"
              currency = 144
          else
              currency = 168
          end
          stock = detail[:stock].gsub(/[^\d]/, '-')
          cost = price[0].gsub(",", "").to_f
  end
```

stock instead of just scraping the title string it scrapes the whole paragraph

```
<p-style="margin-top:-0px;-margin-bottom:0px;-cursor:hand"-title="2-en-su-sucursal"><b>10</b></p>
```

when I only want 2 from the title attribute

Comment: I get a syntax error for the .collect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code. maybe needs a little bit of cleaning but it works. the results are correct but I get a lot of nils.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(search_result.body)
rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]')
i = 0
details = rows.each do |row|
  detail = {}  
  [
    [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
    [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
    [:stock, "td[5]/p/@title"],
    [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
  ].each do |name, xpath|
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
    end
  i = i + 1
  if detail[:sku] != ""
        price = detail[:price].split

        if price[1] == "D"
            currency = 144
        else
            currency = 168
        end
        stock = detail[:stock].each do |anchor|
                puts anchor['title']
                end
        stock1 = stock.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
        cost = price[0].gsub(",", "").to_f
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my untested attempt to fix this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(search_result.body)
rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]')
i = 0
details = rows.each do |row|
  detail = {}  
  [
    [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
    [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
    [:stock, 'td[5]/p[@title]'],
    [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    if name == :stock
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).collect { |p| p[:title].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
    else
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
    end
  end
  i = i + 1
  detail
end
```